# Calling function inside IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

I have the following code:

```
function doStuff() {
    var increaseNumber = 0;

    function doSomeStuff() {
        console.log(++increaseNumber);
    }

    return doSomeStuff();
};

doStuff();
```

When function “doStuff” is executed, function “doSomeStuff”, which is inside function “doStuff”, gets triggered via “return doSomeStuff()” and increments variable “increaseNumber” by 1 each time it is called. If I change “return doSomeStuff();” to “return doSomeStuff;”, calling “doStuff” via “doStuff()” doesn’t work, as I’d assume.

Furthermore, I have the following code which yields the same result as the previous code:

```
var doStuff = (function () {
    var increaseNumber = 0;

    function doSomeStuff() {
        console.log(++increaseNumber);
    }

    return doSomeStuff;
})();

doStuff();
```

In this code, an IIFE is stored inside variable “doStuff”. Inside the IIFE, function “doSomeStuff” is stored and apparently gets triggered via “return doSomeStuff” and increments variable “increaseNumber” by 1 each time it is called via “doStuff()”. **When I change “return doSomeStuff;” to “return doSomeStuff();”, the code doesn’t work as laid out anymore.**

When:

```
    return doSomeStuff();
})();

//doStuff();
```

the IIFE and “doSomeStuff” are executed once and increaseNumber is = 1. Calling the IIFE further times via “doStuff()” doesn’t work, because of error: “JavaScript error: doStuff is not a function”.

There are mostly two things that I don’t understand here:

1. Why does the code work when “return doSomeStuff;”. I don’t see how this triggers function “doSomeStuff”, as the () is missing. When I call a function, I make sure to add (). That’s how I learned it.
2. ABOVE EVERYTHING: Why can I not call “doStuff” as a function when I change “return doSomeStuff;” to “return doSomeStuff();”?

You will notice that I’m still a Javascript novice rather. I hope I’m not repeating a question here (I honestly couldn’t find anything via search or on Google which would answer my query).

Thanks a million for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this code, an IIFE is stored inside variable “doStuff”

No, the IIFE is run immediately, and its **return value** is stored in `doStuff`. So if you want `doStuff` to be a function that you can call multiple times, you need to return a function.

> Why does the code work when “return doSomeStuff;”. I don’t see how this triggers function “doSomeStuff”, as the () is missing.

It's not going to trigger doSomeStuff, not on its own. The code inside the IIFE is just trying to *create* the function, not actually run it. The spot where you call the function is the `()` at the end of `doStuff()`.

> Why can I not call “doStuff” as a function when I change “return doSomeStuff;” to “return doSomeStuff();”?

Because in that case, your IIFE is returning a number, and then that number gets assigned to `doStuff`.

Comment: Just the right answer which touched upon the points I was struggling with: The fact that if you want to utilize a variable that stores an IIFE as a function, it actually needs to return a function. And that "doSomeStuff" is not actually triggered by "return doSomeStuff" but by () at the end of the IIFE. It made it all clear.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript functions are just like any other objects, we can return a function from another function, they can be passed as arguments to other functions etc.

When you `return doSomeStuff;` you are returning the function.

When you `return doSomeStuff();` you are returning the value returned by invoking doSomeStuff function. It is same as

```
    var result = doSomeStuff();
    return result;
```

Now to answer the questions.

`1. Why does the code work when “return doSomeStuff;”. I don’t see how this triggers function “doSomeStuff”, as the () is missing. When I call a function, I make sure to add (). That’s how I learned it.`

As mentioned above you are returning the function here, Which gets stored to `var doStuff`. And it gets executed when you do `doStuff()`

`2. ABOVE EVERYTHING: Why can I not call “doStuff” as a function when I change “return doSomeStuff;” to “return doSomeStuff();”?`

If you change to `return doSomeStuff();` you are not returning function anymore, instead you are returning the value returned by `doSomeStuff` function and gets stored to `var doStuff`. You can do `()` only on functions, since  `doStuff` is not function you cant do `doStuff()`

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript `return func();` returns the value which is returned by `func()`. On the other hand `return func;` returns a `function`, that itself returns the value returned by the `function func`. Both are two different things.
`return func` returns a function object. In javascript functions are treated as objects. `return func` will return the callable function object. Returning `func()` returns the value returned by the callable function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it works.

Q1 (rephrased): "Why does this work?"

```
var doStuff = (function () {
  var increaseNumber = 0;

  function doSomeStuff() {
    console.log(++increaseNumber);
  }

  return doSomeStuff;
})();

doStuff();
```

A1: Let's break it down to simple steps.

1. The variable `doStuff` is declared.
2. The IIFE runs, returning the function declaration `doSomeStuff`, which gets assigned to the variable `doStuff`.
3. Since the variable `doStuff` now holds a function, you can call it as you would call a normal function.

Please note, the once the IIFE has finished, the variable `increaseNumber` remains enclosed in its inner scope and is accessible to the function `doSomeStuff`. This inner scope doesn't get destroyed for the lifetime of `doSomeStuff`, which is now assigned to `doStuff`; This is why calling `doStuff()` leads to the desired effect, i.e. `console.log` outputs a number increment every time the function gets executed.

Q2 (rephrased): "Why can't I call `doStuff` as a function?"

```
var doStuff = (function () {
  var increaseNumber = 0;

  function doSomeStuff() {
    console.log(++increaseNumber);
  }

  return doSomeStuff();
})();

doStuff();
```

A2: Again, let's break it down to better understand what happens under the hood.

1. The variable `doStuff` is declared.
2. When the IIFE runs, is calls the function `doSomeStuff`. Since `doSomeStuff` does not explicitly return anything, the JavaScript engine assumes it returns `undefined`. So `doStuff` now holds a value of `undefined`.
3. Since `undefined` is not a function and is therefore not callable, you will get a runtime error `uncaught TypeError: doStuff is not a function`.

Hope it helps.